# In reportState of the Google SmartHome API, temperatureK & spectrumRgb doesn't seem to work together

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I'm trying to make the Google Smart Home API work on Gladys Assistant (it's an open-source home automation software), and I struggle to make Google Integrations tests pass.

This is my onSync:

```
onSync
{
    "requestId": "9164924531720238290",
    "payload": {
        "agentUserId": "9aba8230-9e8d-47b7-9d1c-f4dd8725aad3",
        "devices": [
            {
                "id": "mqtt-lamp-temperature",
                "type": "action.devices.types.LIGHT",
                "traits": [
                    "action.devices.traits.ColorSetting",
                    "action.devices.traits.Brightness",
                    "action.devices.traits.OnOff"
                ],
                "name": {
                    "name": "Lampe Temperature"
                },
                "attributes": {
                    "colorModel": "rgb",
                    "colorTemperatureRange": {
                        "temperatureMinK": 2000,
                        "temperatureMaxK": 9000
                    }
                },
                "deviceInfo": {
                    "model": null
                },
                "roomHint": "Grand Salon",
                "willReportState": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is what I'm sending to reportState:

```
reportState
{
  online: true,
  color: { temperatureK: 3000, spectrumRgb: 8388863 },
  on: true
}
```

This is what the onQuery is returning to the Google API:

```
onQuery
{
  'mqtt-lamp-temperature': {
    online: true,
    color: { temperatureK: 3000, spectrumRgb: 8388863 },
    on: true
  }
}
```

But this is what Google sees in the integrations tests:

```
AssertionError: Expected state to include: 
{"color":{"temperatureK":{"xRange":[2600,3200]}}}, 

actual state: {"color":{"spectrumRGB":8388863},"on":true,"online":true}: expected false to be true
```

[image: google integrations tests]

It seems Google completely ignores the temperatureK attribute when the spectrumRgb attribute is here.

To confirm my theory, I tried to create a lamp that has only spectrumRgb and a light that has only temperatureK, and then it works perfectly. The problem is, in that case, some tests are skipped and I think I won't get validated by Google with that.

My question is:

Why does those attributes do not work together? Can't a light be controlled by its temperature and by it's RGB ?

Do you see anything weird in my implementation?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/colorsetting#rgb,-hsv,-and-color-temperature):

> Color temperature is a linear scale and a subset of the RGB/HSV full spectrum color models.

You're currently trying to send two different color settings to your light ([orange-ish in kelvin](https://academo.org/demos/colour-temperature-relationship/), [deep pink in rgb](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/FF0080)), which is part of the issue you're running into.

You have set your device up in your `SYNC` to support both RGB and temperature, but in your `QUERY`/`EXECUTE` intents, you need to send *either* temperatureK or rgb spectrum values, not both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Indeed, it's not possible to send both temperatureK and spectrumRgb values! It was not very clear for me, as in the automated tests, it looks like a lamp should absolutely implement everything and return everything.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Your JSON format of Query and ReportState is different, include the device id in the ReportState as well, read the google report state docs for more info.

Comment: I didn't post the full JSON to keep the post short, but I was sending the complete JSON. The issue was that I was sending both temperatureK and spectrumRgb, and those options are not compatible together